# Asynchronously adding entries to database from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Let's assume that I have a list of database entries and I want to duplicate them in the database. Would a regular `foreach` and `db.Add()` work, or is there an asynchronous way I should be using with `db.Add()`?

PS: this is not the actual code, just an example of what I'm trying to accomplish

```
var pencils = await db.Pencils.Where(x => x.IsBroken == false).ToListAsync();

foreach (var pencil in pencils)
{
    pencil.ID = 0;
    db.Add(pencil) 
}
await db.SaveChangesAsync()
```

Comment: multiple calls to `db.Add` and then finally calling the `async` version of the SaveChanges is just enough to do async db updates. so, your sample code above is just fine.

Comment: But adding and using await will result in the code waiting, so it's certainly not going to be more responsive from the user and UI point of view.so you gain nothing in terms of performance here, nor see a change in UI speed either

Comment: But, if you don't mind doing it _fire and forget_ style, you don't actually need to `await` the results of your ` SaveAsync` call. And, to be nit-picking, `await`ing a task does not really _"result in your code waiting"_

Comment: Thank you for the answers. @AlbertD.Kallal Once the duplication is complete, the response will trigger a re render of the table listing all the items in the DB on the front end. Am I correct in assuming that waiting for the changes to complete before sending the OK response would be a better practice.

Comment: But don't _wait_, `await`. There's a big difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to duplicate the broken pencils, your code is slightly flawed. You are loading tracked entities, and I'd be assuming that by setting the ID to 0 you'd want to insert new rows where an identity would take over assigning new IDs. EF entities will chuck an exception if you try setting a tracked entity's PK.

Instead:

```
var pencils = await db.Pencils.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.IsBroken == false)
    .ToListAsync();

db.AddRange(pencils);
await db.SaveChangesAsync()
```

`AsNoTracking` ensures the DbContext does not track the entities loaded. This means if we use `Add`, or in this case `AddRange` to add them all at once, provided those entities are declared with an Identity-based PK (Pencil.Id) then EF treats them as new entities and they would be assigned a new PK by the underlying database when saved.

As mentioned in the comments, "awaiting" an operation does not wait for the operation. That would be more along the lines of doing:

```
db.SaveChangesAsync().Wait();
```

... which would block the current thread until the `SaveChanges` completed.

`await` marks a continuation point so that the caller of the encompassing `async` operation can continue and a resumption point will be picked up and executed at some point after the operation is completed. So for instance in a web action handler, the thread that ASP.Net Core or IIS allocated to action the request can be free to pick up and start processing a new request while this runs in the background. The request will get it's response populated and sent back after completion.

Comment: Thank you for the `AsNoTracking()` . That is specifically super helpful. Much appreciated!